# Android permissions for a testcase

Tags: android, android-testing, android-permissions, android-espresso

I'm working on a testcase for my application that should verify the correctness of an file import action. To automatically test this, my plan is to copy a file from my test assets directory into the downloads folder of the device under test and perform the import action using an Espresso test case.

Does somebody have experience with this? I'm running into the issue that my test case has no permission to write anything to the device.

So far I have created a dedicated manifest.xml file for my test application containing the required permission:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

Furthermore, I'm performing this action before my test starts to grant the needed permission to the test case:

```
adb shell pm grant com.my_app_pacakge.test android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE
```

Unfortunately, when I create the file in the downloads directory the following exception is thrown at the moment I try to write contents to the backup file:

```
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /storage/emulated/0/Download/small_backup: open failed: EACCES (Permission denied)
```

The relevant code is the following:

```
public void putBackupFile(String name  ){
        File backupFile = new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory (Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS ).getPath(), name );

        try {
            InputStream is = InstrumentationRegistry.getInstrumentation().getContext().getAssets().open( name );
            FileOutputStream fileOutputStream = new FileOutputStream(backupFile);

            byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];

            int len;

            while ((len = is.read(buffer)) != -1) {
                fileOutputStream.write(buffer, 0, len);
            }

            fileOutputStream.close();
            is.close();
        } catch (IOException e1) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e1);
        }
    }
```

The exception is triggered at: `FileOutputStream fileOutputStream = new FileOutputStream(backupFile);`

Comment: post the code of you creating the file. Because it may be a problem with how your trying to apply the path to the file.

Comment: Changed the post to include the relevant code

Comment: Did you try including the permission also in your app itself? I think I once had a similar problem where the test app would only be able to use permissions the app also had

Comment: Yes, the app does have this permission and this works fine. The problem only happens when I try to write a file to the device from the testcase.

Comment: Maybe I'm doing this in the wrong way: I could also just use the command line to transfer the files. E.g.: "adb push small_backup /mnt/sdcard/Download". I will try this method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering to the original question: If you grant android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE from adb, you have to grant android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE as well:

```
adb shell pm grant com.my_app_pacakge.test android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE
```

It seems to be that if one ask for WRITE permission in an app, the READ permission is asked/granted automatically. If one does it from adb, the READ permission have to be granted additionally.

Answer (score 0):

I realized that the appraoch states in my question was not the best approach: I have solved this in another way: transferring the required files using the adb command line:

adb push small_backup /mnt/sdcard/Download

This statement is integrated in my test setup (executed before running the test). In the test case I take for granted that the required files are available.